# How to link google sign with email and password authentication for android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I can't find enough data in firebase tutorial to know How to link Google sign with email and password authentication for android. I need to sign with Google first then with email and password

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a password to an existing Firebase User signed in with Google, you just call [`updatePassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePassword(java.lang.String)) on the currentUser.

If you want to link a Google credential to an email/password user, you just call [`linkWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#linkWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)) using the Google AuthCredential on the currentUser.

Afterwards you should be able to sign in the user with either credential.

Comment: I wasn't able to properly find an appropriate answer from docs. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.  :)